# Google analytics tracking page visits or state

Tags: google-analytics

## Code example

```
$(function () {
  (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function () {
      (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
  })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-[Site]-[Nr]', [SiteLabel]);
  ga('set', {
    'dimension1': [State],
    'dimension2': [Title],
    'dimension3': [LocationID],
    'dimension4': [Owner],
    'dimension5': [UserID],
    'dimension6': [Uri],
    'dimension7': [Exception]
  });
  ga('send', 'pageview');
});
```

## Use case example

Use cases where `[A, B, C, D]` are different pages and `S*` is the session.

```
#Use case 1
------------------
S1 : A B A B
S2 : A B A
S3 : B

#Use case 2
------------------
S1 : A B A C A D A

#Use case 3 
------------------
S1 : A B C D 

#Use case 4
------------------
S1 : A A A A A
```

## Expected results:

> **Mode 1:** Hit – value is applied to the single hit for which it has been set.
>
> **Mode 2:** Session – value is applied to all hits in a single session.

```
#Use case 1
  Mode 1:
    A : 4 visits  
    B : 4 visits 
  Mode 2:
    A : 2 visits 
    B : 3 visits 
#Use case 2
  Mode 1:
    A : 4 visits  
    B : 1 visits 
    C : 1 visits  
    D : 1 visits 
  Mode 2:
    A : 1 visits  
    B : 1 visits 
    C : 1 visits  
    D : 1 visits  
#Use case 3 
  Mode 1:
    A : 1 visits  
    B : 1 visits 
    C : 1 visits  
    D : 1 visits  
  Mode 2:
    A : 1 visits  
    B : 1 visits 
    C : 1 visits  
    D : 1 visits  
#Use case 4
  Mode 1:
    A : 5 visits  
  Mode 2:
    A : 1 visits
```

## Results I seem to get

Changing the scope does not seem to have any effect.

```
#Use case 1
  A : 2 (7 page visits)
  B : 1 (1 page visits)
#Use case 2
  A : 1 (7 page visits)
#Use case 3
  A : 1 (4 page visits)
#Use case 4
  A : 1 (5 page visits)
```

## Question

How can I get expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First since you are setting custom dimensions I believe `[A, B, C, D]` should represent different values of custom dimensions, not pages.

When using Hit Level Custom Dimensions you should be looking at pageviews instead of visits/sessions. So what you really should be expecting to see is:

```
#Use case 1
  Mode 1:
    A : 4 pageviews  
    B : 4 pageviews 
  Mode 2:
    A : 2 visits 
    B : 3 visits 
#Use case 2
  Mode 1:
    A : 4 pageviews  
    B : 1 pageviews 
    C : 1 pageviews  
    D : 1 pageviews 
  Mode 2:
    A : 1 visits  
    B : 1 visits 
    C : 1 visits  
    D : 1 visits  
#Use case 3 
  Mode 1:
    A : 1 pageviews  
    B : 1 pageviews 
    C : 1 pageviews  
    D : 1 pageviews  
  Mode 2:
    A : 1 visits  
    B : 1 visits 
    C : 1 visits  
    D : 1 visits  
#Use case 4
  Mode 1:
    A : 5 pageviews  
  Mode 2:
    A : 1 visits
```

If you redo your tests with this in mind the numbers should match.

Comment: It had quite a big delay in my case and it took +24h for dimension change to take effect.

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't change dimension types. Try to create a new set instead to test each other.